Questions on Markov Chains
I took a computer science course where we learned about how to code and simulate Markov Chains.
I learned that the Limiting Distribution is the vector containing the probability of the Markov Chain being in any given state at infinite time, and a Stationary Distribution is the distribution that satisfies P = pi*P.
I also learned the meaning of terms like Ergodic : When it is possible to eventually go from any state to any state  (this is also called Irreducible). On the other hand, Aperiodic means that if for all states, it is only possible to return to them in an odd-number of turns.
We also learned that sometimes for a specific Markov Chain, the Limiting Distribution or the Stationary Distribution don't always exist.
But some questions still remain:

How do I know a Stationary Distribution exists? Is there some mathematical proof for this?
How do I know a Limiting Distribution exists? Is there some mathematical proof for this?
(Provided both exist) When is the Limiting Distribution equal to the Stationary Distribution? When is the Limiting Distribution not equal to the Stationary Distribution? Is there some mathematical proof for this?

Can someone please point me in the right direction and how to prove these?

Hi everyone! Please accompany any down-votes and/or close-votes with some explanation of what the OP can do to improve the question. It seems reasonable and provides adequate context.

A stationary distribution exists because $1$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix.

Hi: you're asking about the whole field of markov chain monte carlo in a question. That's a difficult question but this well known paper on MH could possibly get you started. It doesn't answer all the questions you have but the references section probably contains articles that do. https://biostat.jhsph.edu/~mmccall/articles/chib_1995.pdf
